# Based on a Variable Start Date + Days Interval, I need to find the next date after the current day

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date, sql-server-2008

I have an Anchor Date, eg. 01-01-2020, which is a variable.  I also have a days interval, eg. 7 days, which is also a variable. I need to get the next date on or after the current date which is a whole number of intervals after the anchor date.

It's 01-16-2020 right now.  The date I would expect is 01-22-2020.

The result date will be within a SELECT Statement as a column. The select statement provides the variables.

Comment: Please tag your question with the database that you are using. Date functions are highly vendor-specific.

Comment: I think you need sample data, desired results, an appropriate database tag and an explanation.  Why doesn't `anchor_date + @x * interval '1 day'` (or the equivalent) work?

Comment: The solution to this (assuming there even is one) will be RDBMS-specific. Please tell us what database you're using.

Comment: Sorry Everyone I'm on SQL 2008 R2, no laughing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider:

```
dateadd(
    day,
    7 - datediff(day, '2020-01-01', cast(getdate() as date)) % 7,
    cast(getdate() as date)
)
```

Where the anchor date is `'2020-01-01'` and `7` is the interval.

This works by taking the days difference between the current date and the anchor: for today 2020-01-16, result is 15. Then we get the modulo 7 of this value (which is 1), and substract it from 7 (gives 6), which gives us the number of days that we need to add to the current date to get the expected value (2020-01-22).

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=e38866bf0746bfb49b5822ef29be0658)**

Comment: Awesome!  Thanks @GMB!  I can't upvote as I need 4 more points.